# Convolution as a $L^1$ limit of translates.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I would like what convolution is, as a $L^1$ limit. Namely let $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ (with some further conditions). Then what conditions on $f$ and $g$ ensure that $f\ast g$ is the $L^1$ limit for $h\rightarrow 0$ of finite sums of the form $\sum_{k} f(\cdot-kh)g(kh)h$?. I suppose this should hold if e.g. $f$ is general and $g$ compactly supported and continuous?

Is this a consequence of a more general result, expressing the Lebesgue integral as a limit of "Riemann sums" of sorts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really more a comment than an answer. I need your answer to a question below in order to figure out the right answer to your question. This won't fit into the comment box; read the following, answer the question at the bottom and then I'll post an answer to your question.

First I feel compelled to clean up the notation. For $x\in\Bbb R$ define the translation operator $\tau_x$ by $$\tau_xf(t)=f(t-x).$$

Now here's a fact:

**Theorem 0** Suppose $f,g\in L^1(\Bbb R)$. For $h>0$ define $f_h$ by $$f_h=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}a_k\tau_{kh}f,$$where $$a_k=\int_{kh}^{(k+1)h}g.$$Then $||f_h-f*g||_1\to0$ as $h\to0$.

And now my question for you is

**Q:** *Do* you know Theorem 0, and how to prove it?

The reason I ask: If you're not aware of Theorem 0 then it seems quite possible to me that, depending on why you care about this, you really asked the wrong question; it seems quite likely that Theorem 0 is what you really want.

On the other hand if you're aware of Theorem 0 and you're wondering about precisely the question you asked, the appropriate answer is different. (It's not hard to show, using Theorem 0, that (for example) assuming $g$ is continuous with compact support is enough to do what you asked.)

Comment: $\mathbf{A}$: no I don't know it (I don't know whether it is a standard theorem or not), but I think I can imagine how to prove it. thanks!

Comment: Lemme know if you want the proof of Theorem 0 or details on how the thing about $g\in C_c$ follows. Hint for Theorem 0: Assume first that $g$ is supported on $[A,A+h]$, let $a=\int g$ and use Fubini to show that $||a\tau_Af-g*f||_1\le||g||_1\sup_{0<\delta<h}||f-\tau_\delta f||_1$. The fact that $||f-\tau_\delta f||_1\to0$ as $\delta\to0$ is in the book...